# How do you syllabify "anxious" or "luxury" or "taxi"?

Tags: phonemes

The grapheme X can sometimes be pronounced with a two-phoneme sequence, such as the following:

- /ks/ - taxi
- /gz/ - exact
- /kʃ/ - anxious
- /ŋz/ - anxiety
- /gʒ/ - luxury

For these two-phoneme sequences, I'm wondering how the 2 phonemes are split across syllables.

When the X comes at the end of the first syllable... does the second phoneme from the X get pronounced when you start the second syllable?

- /ˈtæk.si/?
- /ɪɡˈzækt/
- /ˈæŋ(k)ʃəs/
- /ˌæŋ(ɡ)ˈzaɪ.ə.ti/
- /ˈlʌɡ.ʒə.ɹi/

Or is there another way to think about this?

Comment: That depends on the syllabic theory you follow. For my part, I would split all of these, though I wouldn't worry about unavoidable consonants like /(k)/.

Comment: Would love to read more on syllabic theory... any links or resources you can point me towards?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the two cases you've mentioned where the syllable after the consonant cluster is stressed, it is fairly unanimously agreed that the syllabification goes between the two consonants. Thus:

- /ɪɡˈzækt/
- /ˌæŋˈzaɪ.ə.ti/

As I wrote in my answer to [Why is Anxiety Sometimes Pronounced With a 'g' sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/342570/77227), it's actually not typical for *anxiety* to have a [g] between the [ŋ] and [z]. That pronunciation would only be found in an accent where syllable-final [ŋg] exists—such accents exist, but the use of syllable-final [ŋg] instead of [ŋ] is considered a regionalism rather than a neutral feature of the English sound system.

Your other examples are harder.

In the case of *taxi,* an "onset maximizing" approach to syllabification would yield /ˈtæk.si/. However, there is a competing principle of syllabifying as many consonants as possible with the adjacent syllable with greater stress, explained by John Wells in "[Syllabification and allophony](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/syllabif.htm)" (originally published in Susan Ramsaran (ed.), *Studies in the pronunciation of English,* A commemorative volume in honour of A.C. Gimson (London and New York: Routledge, 1990)). That principle would yield the syllabification /ˈtæks.i/.

In my view, adopting Wells's principle makes it a little problematic to determine how *anxious* and *luxury* are syllabified, because it raises the question of whether /ŋ(k)ʃ/, /kʃ/ and /gʒ/ are ever possible coda clusters in English, which I find difficult to answer. On the one hand, no English words in common use end in /ŋ(k)ʃ/, /kʃ/ or /gʒ/. But on the other hand, I think they are easily pronounceable as-is in word-final position for most English speakers, and /kʃ/ at least would not tend to be replaced by any other sequence in proper names such as Baksh, Buksh or Anksh (I haven't found any proper names ending in /gʒ/). I can also imagine English speakers pronouncing these sequences at the end of words formed as clippings, e.g. when "anxious" is truncated to "anxsh" (compare "usual" > "[yoozh](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51953)"): here's some evidence that this kind of clipping is possible for English speakers:

> Tiffany Schaefer
> @harpandsong
>
> Jonathan came up with a new verb last night, "Anxsh." It's when you're >feeling anxiety for whatever reason and you just need to sit with it and "anxsh" for a bit.  It made me giggle.
>
> 6:40 AM · Apr 29, 2021 -- [Twitter](https://twitter.com/harpandsong/status/1387763648203010064)

Another example of a similar nature is mentioned in the paper "[OMG the Word-final Alveopalatals are Cray-cray Prev(alent): The Morphophonology of Totes Constructions in English](https://opencuny.org/laurenspradlin/files/2016/01/The-Morphophonology-of-Totes-Constructions-in-English-PWPL-22.1.pdf)", by Lauren Spradlin (2016; Volume 22, Issue 1 *Proceedings of the 39th Annual Penn Linguistics Conference*): "perfecsh" as a truncated pronunciation of *perfection* (page 276).

Also see this relevant [comment by Chris Button](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=35569#comment-1542500) (November 30, 2017) on the Language Log post "Ask Language Log: Unnecessary disyllabism?" (by Victor Mair, November 27, 2017).